# How to show audio signal on the screen of raspberry pi? and how to input the sound signal?

Tags: audio, screen, signal

The screen i used is http://www.amazon.co.uk/Touch-Screen-Designed-Raspberry-Model/dp/B00UV78E9Q/ref=sr_1_14?ie=UTF8&qid=1432902157&sr=8-14&keywords=raspberry+pi+2
I would like to know how to input the audio signal into the raspberry pi and how to show the spectrum of the signals at the same time in the screen.
Any programming or extra components i need?
Please help me. Thank you.

Now I determine to use a USB audio input the sound signals. But how could the spectrum or other graphs of the signals display on the screen?
Much thanks.

Comment: Since rpi doesn't have a built in mic, you will have to consider using USB mic or something like that.

Comment: The Raspberry Pi is irrelevant to the question.  Any Linux solution should work.

Answer (score 1):

I would look at installing [Audacity](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/sound/audacity) - you can find it in the raspbian repositories, just do `sudo apt-get install audacity`.